# How to pass a variable along with success data function in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am getting variable after success data is loaded.After that, success variable is there in the hidden field, but how i will get it inside the controller function.Here is my code

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:'<?php echo base_url();?>controller1/get_all',
    data:"sID="+sID+"&hID="+hID,
    success:function(data)
        {
            $("#report").css('visibility', 'visible');

            $('#report').html(data);
            var vID = $("#vID ").val();  
        }
});
```

I am getting hID and SID inside the controller by post.But after success data only will  i get the variable vid,alert displayed VID. How will i get inside controller function.

Comment: Can you make it a little clear?

Comment: after the success data only i will get varaiable VID.So hwill get inside controller($this->input->post('vid');for getting this what will  i do inside success data

Comment: show your get_all method

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**In Controller**

```
$data['status'] = 'TRUE';
$data['number'] = '25';

echo json_encode($data);
```

**In AJAX**

```
success:function(data)
{
    console.log(data); # to print complete data
    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.number);
}
```